# Symfony Easyadmin choice type field for roles

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I use easyadmin, I wish for the field "role" display the choice of roles in a field type "radio" but an error (array to string conversion) of this type occurs (see image below):

[Notice: Array to string conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i73De.png)

here is my config:

```
easy_admin:
entities:
    User:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\User
        form:
            fields:
                - { property: 'username' }
                - { property: 'email' }
                - { property: 'enabled' }
                -   property: 'plainPassword'
                    type: 'repeated'
                    type_options:
                        type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType
                        required: false
                        first_options: { label: '%label.password%' }
                        second_options: { label: '%label.password_confirmation%' }
                        invalid_message: fos_user.password.mismatch
                -   property: 'roles'
                    type: 'choice'
                    type_options:
                        mapped: true
                        expanded: true
                        multiple: false
                        choices: { 'Conseiller': 'ROLE_USER', 'Administrateur': 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

Someone would have a solution to offer me so that I can display radio buttons with easyadmin?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution in Symfony 3.4 to this (uses Yes/No dropdown) that might help:

in config.yml

```
imports:
    ...
    - { resource: easyAdmin.yml }
```

in easyadmin.yml

```
fields:
    ...
    - property: 'hasRoleAdmin'
      label: 'Is admin?'
      type: choice
      type_options:
        choices:
            'No': 'No'
            'Yes': 'Yes'
```

in User entity:

```
public function hasRoleAdmin()
{
    return ($this->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}

public function setHasRoleAdmin($isAdmin)
{
    if ('Yes' === $isAdmin && 'No' === $this->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $this->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }
    if ('No' === $isAdmin && 'Yes' == $this->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $this->removeRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }
    $this->isAdmin = $isAdmin;
}
```

Comment: @geob your solution works as long as there are only admin and non admin users but it will not work if you have more than two type of users.

Comment: @Daishi Correct. The application for which that method was created only needed two roles.

Answer (score 8):

@johan-rm what you did was almost correct.

In fact you can't use radio buttons for roles because roles (see the `s`) is multiple choice field. You need to use check boxes (or a mulitple select).

In your code, the only thing that was wrong was this part: `multiple: false`.
If you try to map an array to a single choice field, you are trying to map an array to a string, hence the error.
Just change `multiple: false` to `multiple: true`.

This is the result:

```
easy_admin:
entities:
    User:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\User
        form:
            fields:
                - { property: 'username' }
                - { property: 'email' }
                - { property: 'enabled' }
                -   property: 'plainPassword'
                    type: 'repeated'
                    type_options:
                        type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType
                        required: false
                        first_options: { label: '%label.password%' }
                        second_options: { label: '%label.password_confirmation%' }
                        invalid_message: fos_user.password.mismatch
                -   property: 'roles'
                    type: 'choice'
                    type_options:
                        mapped: true
                        expanded: true
                        multiple: true
                        choices: { 'Conseiller': 'ROLE_USER', 'Administrateur': 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

Comment: Thanks. I had an issue when saving new roles: the roles (json format) was saved as an object instead of an array. Adding 'array_values' in the setRoles(roles) method like:
$this->roles = array_values($roles) solved this. This re-indexes the array, and the result is stored as an array in json